# How to setup properly alsa dummy on docker?

Tags: docker, alsa

I was trying to set up the following things https://superuser.com/questions/344760/how-to-create-a-dummy-sound-card-device-in-linux-server?rq=1 on docker container but after all, modprobe didn't work. Do you know some Dockerfile with properly setup alsa with dummy adapter ?

Comment: I am looking intot he same issue - have you resolved it?